# Aligning searchbar to right center

Tags: c#, forms, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add a searchbar to my 'menu bar'. It should be on the right(x) in the middle of the bar(y) but it keeps going like this:

[image]

This is part of my code:

```html
            <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="LightBlue" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="170" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

                <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="White" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Height,Factor=.1,Constant=0}" HeightRequest="40" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" >
                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="1" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"/>
                    <Button Text ="H" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0.5, Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=1}" />

                    <SearchBar x:Name="searchcustomer" Placeholder="Search" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="100" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0.5, Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=1, Constant=0}"/>
                   
                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="1" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"/>
                </RelativeLayout>


                <StackLayout
         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="50">
                        <Label x:Name="NewsButton" Text="News" Font="Bold, 24" TextColor="white"/>
                        <Label x:Name="TaskButton" Text="Tasks" Font="Bold, 24" TextColor="white"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure that is possible using the standalone search bar from Xamarin forms since the default position is left. You may want to explore the possibility of creating a custom search bar from custom controls where you could specify the position of the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Grid` instead of `RelativeLayout` .Refer to the following code.

```
<RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="LightBlue" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="170" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

  <Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />                    
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="1" />

    <Button  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text ="H" HeightRequest="40"  />

    <SearchBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  x:Name="searchcustomer" Placeholder="Search" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>

    <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="1" />

  </Grid>

   //...

</RelativeLayout>
```

And it will look like the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I changed it a bit but the grid layout solution seems to work!